# Updating each column with different value

Tags: php, sql, ip

im a new guy in php i want help ,i google a lot about it but couldn't figure it out. I want to write ips of sites from the table url into a database in a row known as ips.

I use `gethostbyname` to get IP, now what I want to do is get ip of that site stored in url row and store that IP in ips row of the table but I'm nt able to do it: only the first row's URL IP is written in all of the ips columns. Please tell me how to write each URL's IP in the ips column of the corresponding row.

```
<? 
   include"cfg/db.php"; 

   $mirror_al = 
   mysql_query("SELECT * FROM kayitlar"); 
   $mirror = mysql_fetch_array($mirror_al); 
   $siteip=$mirror['url']; 
   $shrt=substr($siteip, 7); 
   $url = rtrim($shrt,"/"); 
   $mystring = $url; 
   $parts = explode("/",$mystring); 
   $mystring = $parts['0']; 
   $fullip=gethostbyname($mystring); 
   echo $fullip; 
   $ekle2 = mysql_query("UPDATE kayitlar set ips='$fullip'"); ?>
```

Comment: without a code it's hard to guess, but i would think you need an array of IPs and a loop to feed each IP to database.

Comment: The Code @Elen
`<?
include"cfg/db.php";
$id = $_GET['id'];
$mirror_al = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM kayitlar");

$mirror = mysql_fetch_array($mirror_al);



 $siteip=$mirror['url'];

       $shrt=substr($siteip, 7);
         $url = rtrim($shrt,"/");
         $mystring = $url;

$parts = explode("/",$mystring);
$mystring = $parts['0'];


        $fullip=gethostbyname($mystring);
echo $fullip;
     $ekle2 = mysql_query("UPDATE kayitlar set ips='$fullip'");


  ?>`

Comment: Edit your question and add the code there. It is completely unreadable as a comment.

Comment: `$mystring = $parts['0'];` attempts to take the element with name `0` from `$parts`. You want the first item, in which case you should use `$parts[0]`.

Comment: @KristianAntonsen now no ip is being echoed or written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not sure why you GET `id` if you don't use it anywhere... i've added `siteid` from database - please see if it works:

```
include"cfg/db.php"; 
$id = $_GET['id']; 

$mirror_al = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM kayitlar"); 

while($mirror = mysql_fetch_array($mirror_al))
  {
    $siteip =$mirror['url']; 
    $siteid = $mirror['id']; // please correct accordingly

    $shrt=substr($siteip, 7); 
    $url = rtrim($shrt,"/"); 
    $mystring = $url; 
    $parts = explode("/",$mystring); 
    $mystring = $parts['0']; 
    $fullip=gethostbyname($mystring); 
    echo $fullip; 

    $ekle2 = mysql_query("UPDATE kayitlar set ips='$fullip' where id='".$siteid."'"); 

}
```

Comment: no, your `siteid` get's from database on fetch. `$id = $_GET['id'];` - this `id` is not used in your original code. or you original code isn't complete?

Comment: now its complete coz of you brother :) @Elen

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is here (or at least the one you are complaining about):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE kayitlar set ips='$fullip'");
```

If you simply call `update` on a table, that will update all records. You need some sort of `where` clause, generally this is some ID from the current table. You also may be able to use `limit 1`  depending on your table structure (I don't know how you have set things up, so I can't give you that answer). If you don't have a way to choose a particular row, you also may want to consider simply using `INSERT` instead.

Here is what you are probably looking for:

```
if($fullip) 
    mysql_query("UPDATE kayitlar set ips='$fullip' where id='".
                   // sanitize your data!
                   mysql_real_escape_string($id) ."'");
```

Comment: i even tried using where clause and all the URLs have onay clause as 0 i set it as mysql_query("UPDATE kayitlar set ips='$fullip' where onay=0");
stll the same problem it updated/inserted all the ips rows with same IP of the first URL .

Comment: Your where clause is not specific enough then.